# Pass a random JSON pair into an aframe component

Tags: json, aframe, webvr

Edit 3: The code is now working across numerous objects (thanks to Noam) and he has also helped in getting the random function working alongside it. I'll update the code in the question once its implemented.

Edit 2: I've taken @Noam Almosnino's answer and am now trying to apply it to an Array with numerous objects (unsuccessfully). Here's the [Remix](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lightning-seeder?path=index.html:21:25) link. Please help!

Edit: I've taken some feedback and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545518/how-to-load-json-data-into-an-a-frame-component) page which talks about using a JSON.parse function. I've edited the code to reflect the new changes but I still can't figure out exactly whats missing.

Original: I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854921/how-to-pass-a-reference-to-aframe-component) previous answer would help in my attempt to parse a json file and return a random string and its related pair (e.g Title-Platform), but I couldn't get it to work. My goal is to render the output as a text item in my scene. I've really enjoyed working with A-frame but am having a hard time finding documentation that can help me in this regard. I tried using the following modified script to get text from the Json file...

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('super', {  // Not working
schema: { 
Games: {type: 'array'}, 
jsonData: {
parse: JSON.parse,
stringify: JSON.stringify}
},
init: function () {
var el = this.el; 
el.setAttribute('super', 'jsonData', {src:"https://cdn.glitch.com/b031cbf1-dd2b-4a85-84d5-09fd0cb747ab%2Ftrivia.json?1514896425219"});
var hugeArray = ["Title", "Platform",...];   
const el.setAttribute('super', {Games: hugeArray}); 
el.setAttribute('position', {x:-2, y:2, z:-3}); 
} 
});
```

The triggers are also set up in my  html to render the text. My code is being worked on through glitch.com, any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. In the example above you declare the variable `el` and refer to `El` with capital `E` underneath.

Comment: you also have an errant const in line 8 there.

Comment: Your array of strings is also incorrectly declared. It should be ```var hugeArray = ["string1", "string2", ...];```

Comment: @Diego Marcos thank you. I corrected the case mismatch but I'm confused by the 'var' declaration, if I use "string1", "string2" etc where do i put the URL reference for the JSON file?

Comment: @AquaVitae Thanks. Would you be able to help me with the correct declaration for the const in line 8?

Comment: Also You cannot pass an array of file URLs and expect them to be fetched and parsed for you. You will have to do it yourself using XMLHttpRequest and JSON.parse.

Comment: @Diego Marcos, thank you for that info, I've looked into the JSON.parse and updated the code. Would I still need to layer a XMLttpRequest ontop of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the json, I think you need to use an XMLHttpRequest (as Diego pointed out in the comments), when that's loaded, you can set the text through setAttribute.

Here's a basic example on glitch:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-json-to-text

On init it does the request, then when done, it set's the loaded json text onto the entity.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('json-text-loader', {
  schema: {},
  init: function () {
    var textEntity = document.querySelector('#text');
    var url = 'json/text.json';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( 'GET', url, true );
    request.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

      var jsonText = JSON.parse( event.target.response )
      textEntity.setAttribute("value", jsonText.text)

    } );
    request.send( null );
  }
});
```

Updated version: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/peppermint-direction

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('json-text-loader', {
  schema: {},
  init: function () {
    var textEntity = document.querySelector('#text');
    var url = 'json/text.json';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( 'GET', url, true );
    request.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

      var games = JSON.parse( event.target.response ).games;

      // Get a random game from the list
      var randomGame = games[Math.floor(Math.random()*games.length)];

      // Get the next game if it's available
      var nextGame = null
      if (games.indexOf(randomGame) < games.length - 1) {
        nextGame = games[games.indexOf(randomGame) + 1]
      }

      // Build the string for the games
      var gameInfo = randomGame.Title + '\n' + randomGame.Developer + '\n\n'
      if (nextGame != null) {
        gameInfo += nextGame.Title + '\n' + nextGame.Developer + '\n'
      }

      textEntity.setAttribute("value", gameInfo);
      var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
      sceneEl.querySelector('a-box').setAttribute('material', {src:"https://cdn.glitch.com/4e63fbc2-a1b0-4e38-b37a-9870b5594af8%2FResident%20Evil.jpg?1514826910998"}); 
    });
    request.send( null );
  }
});
```

Comment: I found this page a few minutes ago which mentions a JSON.parse. Would that also be an option or do you think I have to go this route? Thanks for the feedback Noam.

Comment: JSON.parse takes the contents of the file and converts it to a js object. So you would still need to request the file with XMLHttpRequest.

If you want slightly more abstraction, you could try jQuery's ajax methods:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/


Here's the difference between the two approaches:
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#request

Comment: Thanks for the example you gave Noam it was very helpful. Do you know how I would apply that to a JSON array?

Comment: I'm looking to urgently learn the basics of customizing the parameters of this parse function so any resources you might have / code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll want to loop through the array and build a string with line breaks.

Here's the modified example working with the array:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/comet-cricket

Mozilla has a great reference that should help:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Thanks, the line break is a good starting point for me. Do you know the code to display only a certain number of titles from the whole list?  For example the list has three objects, but lets say I just want line breaks with two and not the entire list.

Comment: I don't think the last extra line break would make much difference in how it's rendered, but you could use an if statement based on the index of the loop. I've modified the example to show that. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/comet-cricket If you want to limit the amount of titles displayed, you could use array.slice (also in the example) to get a subset of they array to loop through. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: You're giving me such great code. I'm trying to combine it with this random variable someone gave me but something is not lining up for some reason - [link to variable code snippet](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lightning-seeder?path=index.html:20:5)

Comment: I think you want it like this: `var random = jsonGames[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]` Then each time the page loads the title is random.

Comment: I am using the random variable, but combining it with that code you wrote is proving troublesome. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/freckle-catamaran?path=index.html:25:12

Comment: I'm trying to understand better: You want to show a random game from the list, but you only want to use the first two entries from the list. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's right, so in a list I want to get a random game and the next ones directly underneath (like you showed me earlier).

Comment: When you say the next ones directly underneath, do you mean just the next game in the list after the random one, or the rest of the list after the random game?

Comment: Just the next game.

Comment: I modified the answer above to latest.
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/peppermint-direction

Comment: You might have given me a nice gift for when I wake up Tomorrow morning. Can I buy you a coffee friend?

Comment: Happy to have been of help. No coffee needed, but if you can mark the answer, that would be great!